# função is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

Este código estava funcionando sem me mostrar erros. Aí eu coloquei um setTimeOut, ele continua funcionando, mas dá um erro chato no log do browser, dizendo que a função não está definida. Devo estar colocando o setTimeOut de forma errada. Eis o código:

```
 setTimeout(function montaAlua(){


      let montarAula = {

        idUsuario: document.querySelector('#id').textContent,
        token: document.querySelector('#token').textContent,
        id: document.querySelector('#ultima-aula').textContent
      };

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var variavel = document.querySelector('#token-servico').innerHTML;

     xhr.open("POST", "http://54.233.209.248:8080/nuite- 
  web/rest/courses/findById", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + variavel);
      xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){

        if(xhr.status == 200){


          let curso = xhr.responseText;
          curso = JSON.parse(curso);

          let video = '';
          video += curso.video;
          document.querySelector('#video').innerHTML = video;

          let descricao ='';
          descricao += curso.descricao;
          document.querySelector('#curso-descricao').innerHTML = descricao;

        }
      });
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(montarAula));
    }, 1000 );

montaAlua();
```

Comment: Pode colocar a imagem do erro no browser.

Comment: Cuidado, parece que o nome da sua função está errada: `montaAlua()`. Não deveria ser `montaAula()` ?

Comment: Sim.. está errado, mas não é o nome da função. Elas coincidem na primeira e última linha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mostrando o erro porque você esta definindo a função como parâmetro do `setTimeout`. Veja:

```js
setTimeout(function montaAlua(){ console.log('Funcionou!'); }, 1000);

montaAlua();
```

O correto é você definir a função e passar ela como parâmetro no método `setTimeout`

```js
function montaAlua() {
  console.log('Funcionou!');
}

setTimeout(montaAlua, 1000);
```

> Note ao passar função como parâmetro, não é utilizado os parenteses, se utilizar, a função será executada imediatamente.

Ou simplesmente:

```js
setTimeout(function montaAlua(){ console.log('Funcionou!'); }, 1000);
```